# How to map Ctrl-B to delete character under cursor in insert mode?

Tags: vim

I've tried

```
:inoremap ^b <Del>
:inoremap ^b Del
:imap ^b <Del>
:imap ^b Del
```

And they all seem to insert a `^B` character.

I'm using gVim7 with Windows 7x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format for the control character is not what vim expects.  You want to use `<C-x>` for control characters in mappings.

```
:inoremap <C-b> <Del>
```

As your current mapping stands vim is mapping <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: Cheers! Knew it was something simple. Throws me off that `:h i_^b` works like `:h i_<c-b>`.